# How can I slim down all my bloated photoshop files at one time?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a massive 8 TB worth of 15 years of Photoshop Work. In recent years I have done better at organizing my photoshop layers and deleting unused layers, but is there a solution that would allow me to go back and mass delete empty layers in photoshop of every file on my server. Perhaps a script.

Comment: Is it just PURE Photoshop files?  Are you including source files and fonts?  I wouldn't trust a script enough to go in and modify layers.  I would see if you can consolidate the work in regards to the typography, origs, supplied, etc. etc.  If you have a finished file that is several years old I see no logical purpose in keeping the client's originals.  I would just keep the source files and design files.

Comment: an empty layer isn't likely adding much data to your files. In other words, I don't think empty layers are your issue.

Comment: What @DA01 said. I'd assume an empty layer probably doesn't use more than a few KBs. You'd probably gain a lot of space by deleting hidden layers, but that's incredibly dangerous and probably not something you can do in a batch.

Comment: Also, calculate the cost in time you'd spend doing this vs. the cost of a few hard drives.

Comment: Yes your right @DA01 a 8 TB drive costs $260 so given that you may want to have backup also that would be still ~600  (to a thousand dollars). On the other hand how much would you free up things? 10% so not much worth doing anything for a 60$ retuyrn on investment.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a batch action from a default PS script that deletes all the empty layers.

The script can be accessed here:
File › Scripts › Delete all empty layers